# Creating author blocks in beamer using authblk package

Tags: beamer, affiliation, authblk

I am trying to use \authblk to create a beamer presentation with multiple author blocks, where each block basically says:

> AUTHOR NAME 1
>
> INSTITUTION 1

I tried using the \authblk but it does not seem to work. Can anyone please help me?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage{authblk}

\usepackage{color,colortbl}

\title[Short title]{Long Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author[Short Name (U ABC)]{Author 1\\Institute 1 \and Author 2\\Institute 2 \and Author 3\\Institute 3}

\date[Dec 2015]{December 2015}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use [`authblk`](http://ctan.org/pkg/authblk). Rather set the authors in separate `\column`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\title[Short title]{Long Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author[Short Name (U ABC)]{%
  \texorpdfstring{%
    \begin{columns}
      \column{.3333\linewidth}
      \centering
      Author 1 \\ Institute 1
      \column{.3333\linewidth}
      \centering
      Author 2 \\ Institute 2
      \column{.3333\linewidth}
      \centering
      Author 3 \\ Institute 3
    \end{columns}
 }
 {Author 1, Author 2, Author 3}
}

\date[Dec 2015]{December 2015}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The use of `\texorpdfstring{<tex>}{<pdf string>}` helps with the fact that `\author` automatically completes the PDF properties' author field. Now you can switch between what is displayed visually in the presentation, and that of the document properties.

Comment: Great! That works perfectly. I prefer to break up the author blocks over two rows, so I've posted a modified code separately. Thank you @werner :)

Comment: Could you please explain the use of the command: \texorpdfstring{<tex>}{<pdf string>} a little bit? What does it exactly do?

Comment: @rainman: `\texorpdfstring{<TeX>}{<PDF>}` takes two arguments. The first contains TeX-related content, while the latter might contain PDF-specific content. It's often used when content being set has comparable entries in a PDF's structure. For example, when one issues `\author{<author>}`, `<author>` ends up in the PDF info (when pressing Ctrl+D in Adobe Reader). However, if it's set in the document, it could be set in **bold**. The formatting is not supported in the PDF attributes, so one may issue `\author{\texorpdfstring{\bfseries <author>}{<author>}}` to discern between the two components.

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to @werner's code, here is a version that allows me to break up the author blocks over two rows. Thanks @werner!

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\title[Short title]{Long Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author[Short Name (U ABC)]{%
  \texorpdfstring{%
    \begin{columns}
      \column{.3\linewidth}
      \centering
      Author 1 \\ Institute 1
      \column{.3\linewidth}
      \centering
      Author 2 \\ Institute 2
    \end{columns}
    \vspace{12pt}
    \begin{columns}
      \column{.3\linewidth}
      \centering
      Author 3 \\ Institute 3
    \end{columns}
 }
 {Author 1, Author 2, Author 3}
}

\date[Dec 2015]{December 2015}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```